# How to Read a Binary String from Right to Left?

Tags: c#, binary, bit

i'm having a code in which a String is consists of Binary Code i want to read it from Right to left.
Can Someone Suggest me Better Way to Read the Binary String .

```
 string myString;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\tvin.exe", FileMode.Open))
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        myString = Convert.ToBase64String(bin);
    }

    byte[] rebin = Convert.FromBase64String(myString);
    using (FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("C:\\tvout.exe", FileMode.Create))
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs2))
        bw.Write(rebin);
```

> The thing is we can read a String from Left to string but i  want to
>   read in Right to Left, IF u Reverse the String then the Order of the
>   Binary bits is changing .So please Suggest me Some Solution.

Comment: What about reversing string then then reading it from right to left?

Comment: is the string you want to reverse the Base64String ? use a toCharArray and loop over array elements from lentgh-1 to 0 inclusive

Comment: what exactly is in reversed order? the chars of the string? or the read Bytes?

Comment: Reading the Bytes from the string which contains N Number of BIts..

Comment: I think you should put some example strings and read/write bytes into your code, this would help us a lot understanding your problem